# HighCharts - two Y-axis, one with max value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have problem with Highcharts, I've set right Y-axis to min:0 and max:100 (it's %) but it won't work and make 125 percentage.
What's wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/SdTcU/

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            colors: ['#c42525','#8bbc21'],
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                            '07:00:00','07:15:00','07:30:00','07:45:00','08:00:00','08:15:00','08:30:00','08:45:00','09:00:00','09:15:00','09:30:00','09:45:00','10:00:00','10:15:00','10:30:00','10:45:00','11:00:00','11:15:00','11:30:00','11:45:00','12:00:00','12:15:00','12:30:00','12:45:00','13:00:00','13:15:00','13:30:00','13:45:00','14:00:00','14:15:00','14:30:00','14:45:00','15:00:00','15:15:00','15:30:00','15:45:00','16:00:00','16:15:00','16:30:00','16:45:00','17:00:00','17:15:00','17:30:00','17:45:00','18:00:00','18:15:00','18:30:00','18:45:00','19:00:00','19:15:00','19:30:00','19:45:00','20:00:00','20:15:00','20:30:00','20:45:00','21:00:00','21:15:00','21:30:00','21:45:00','22:00:00','22:15:00','22:30:00','22:45:00','23:00:00','23:15:00'
                            ],
                labels: {
                    step: 4,
                    rotation: -45,
                    align: 'right',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '10px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    format: '{value}',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: '1',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                title: {
                    text: '%',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    format: '{value}%',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: '1',
                data: [
                    null, null, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                    35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 
                    35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 
                    24000, 23000, 22000, 21000, 20000,
                    null, null, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                    24000, 23000, 22000, 21000, 20000,
                    24000, 23000, 22000, 21000, 20000
                    ]
            }, {
                name: '2',
                data: [
                    1, null, null, null, null, 1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618,27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826,
                    100, 1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618,27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826,
                    1000, 1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618,27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826
                    ]
            },
            {
                name: '%',
                color: '#4572A7',
                type: 'spline',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [80,70,78,86,64,51,58,88,88,100,100,95,68,91,92,93,94,85,100]
            }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out.
Better way to fix this issue is use tickinterval.

Here is sample
http://jsfiddle.net/SdTcU/1/

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            colors: ['#c42525','#8bbc21'],
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                            '07:00:00','07:15:00','07:30:00','07:45:00','08:00:00','08:15:00','08:30:00','08:45:00','09:00:00','09:15:00','09:30:00','09:45:00','10:00:00','10:15:00','10:30:00','10:45:00','11:00:00','11:15:00','11:30:00','11:45:00','12:00:00','12:15:00','12:30:00','12:45:00','13:00:00','13:15:00','13:30:00','13:45:00','14:00:00','14:15:00','14:30:00','14:45:00','15:00:00','15:15:00','15:30:00','15:45:00','16:00:00','16:15:00','16:30:00','16:45:00','17:00:00','17:15:00','17:30:00','17:45:00','18:00:00','18:15:00','18:30:00','18:45:00','19:00:00','19:15:00','19:30:00','19:45:00','20:00:00','20:15:00','20:30:00','20:45:00','21:00:00','21:15:00','21:30:00','21:45:00','22:00:00','22:15:00','22:30:00','22:45:00','23:00:00','23:15:00'
                            ],
                labels: {
                    step: 4,
                    rotation: -45,
                    align: 'right',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '10px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                tickInterval:10750, //get max value from highest area and divide it by 4
                labels: {
                    format: '{value}',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: '1',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                tickInterval:20, //set ticks to 20
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                title: {
                    text: '%',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    format: '{value}%',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: '1',
                data: [
                    null, null, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                    35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 
                    35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 
                    24000, 23000, 22000, 21000, 20000,
                    null, null, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                    24000, 23000, 22000, 21000, 20000,
                    24000, 23000, 22000, 21000, 20000
                    ]
            }, {
                name: '2',
                data: [
                    1, null, null, null, null, 1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618,27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826,
                    100, 1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618,27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826,
                    1000, 1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618,27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826
                    ]
            },
            {
                name: '%',
                color: '#4572A7',
                type: 'spline',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [80,70,78,86,64,51,58,88,88,100,100,95,68,91,92,93,94,85,100]
            }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: with or without setting a tickInterval, it is still best to set alignTicks to false, and hide the grid lines on one of the axes.

Comment: Sorry, that's not a better way, as soon as you change the data - it'll break to have the same problem as before.

Comment: Yes, but i get data with php so I always calculate max and min :)

Answer (score 25):

The problem you're having is that highcharts is trying to align the ticks. There are two ways of handling this problem with the current data set:

```
max: 100
```

changes to

```
max: 75
```

or, you need to set alignTicks as false

```
chart: {
    type: 'area',
    alignTicks: false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may also use a combination of the solutions above (worked for me):

```
alignTicks: false (chart)
max:100 (on % axis)
gridLineWidth: 0 (on second Y axis)
```