# Highcharts: how to optimize auto-scaling so that columns make better use of the available height

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts columns sometimes don't make proper use of the available height, in some cases leaving nearly the upper half of a chart empty. After fiddling with the official example charts I noticed that the y-axis max extreme (internally) seems to be dependent on the chart's container height.

For example, the [Highcharts example for stacked column chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/):

The original example (`container` height of **400px**) has a max of **12.5** for the y-axis with the largest columns having a value of 11. **~90%** of the chart height are used.

[image: Original example at 400px]

When modifying the height to **300px**, y-axis max changes to **15**, so that only **~75%** of the height is used.

[image: Same example at 300px]

When modifying the height to **200px**, y-axis max changes to **20**, only **~55%** of the height being used.

[image: Same example at 200px]

Is there a way to improve this behavior without programmatically setting the axis extremes whenever the displayed data changes? You might argue that applying such a small height to a column chart is a weird thing to do, but this is just an example, I have seen similar behavior with larger charts (having other data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related with fact, that defaulty highcharts has enabled [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding). Set that parameter as 0 to fillout area more efficient.

```
yAxis: {
   maxPadding:0
}
```

Comment: Using a custom `maxPadding` together with `endOnTicks:false` fixed the height of the columns in the given examples, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The example charts could be fixed with [Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32068980/1006823). After applying the change to my own chart, I noticed another problem that screwed up the scale even more, but was not part of this question - adding this as another answer, just for the sake of completeness.

My chart consisted of combined column/line chart with a 2nd y-axis. Depending on its values, the line chart series had strange effects on the scale of the columns (even if the line chart series was empty). Doing some more research I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16511052/1006823) pointing me to Highcharts' [`alignTicks` option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks), setting it to `false` resolved the issue.